# Question on overriding equals & calling equals recursively

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, equals

So I overwrote an equals function that works with Nodes that contain objects. and it looks like this.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    // Checks if obj is from the same class as this Deque.
    if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // If obj is from the same class, casts object to DoublyLinkedDeque.
    DoublyLinkedDeque<T> object = (DoublyLinkedDeque<T>) obj;
    Node other = object.front;
    Node self = this.front;

    // Checks the info of every Node in this Deque with the other.
    while (self != null && other != null) { // Checks
        if (!(self.info.equals(other.info))) return false;
        self = self.next;
        other = other.next;
    }
    // Otherwise, checks if the front of both Deques is null.
    return (self == null && other == null);
}
```

And it works but I'm not sure how the second invocation of equals work. Specifically how does my code check if the info field (that contains objects) of two nodes are equal without calling `super.equals`? Nothing in my function has the capability to check if two objects are equal as far as I know, can someone explain this?

Comment: I see no recursion.  Node.equals() calls what I assume to be T.equals(),  if the 'info' member has type T.   Node.equals() iterates through its own nodes list.  Nowhere does Node.equals call Node.equals, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: I see, sorry I guess my question isn't really about recursion! I'm asking about the line (self.info.equals(other.info)) which I assume is comparing the info field of two nodes, which contain objects. I am wondering how the program is comparing these two objects. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: self.info and other.info are member fields of the Node. They are objects of some class, call it T.  So when you call `self.info.equals(other.info), that's a call on the equals method of the T class. You need to look at the definition of class T for that code. This is an absolutely normal pattern for implementing equals -- if your class contains other objects, then objects of your class are equal iff the objects they contain are all equal.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering about this for hours but I get it know. Yes, the equals function of my T class is just the regular equals function that was inherited from Object so your explanation makes a lot of sense.